# How to plot Autocorrelation plot and Partial Autocorrelation plot in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

How to plot ACF plot and PACF plot for a time series in R using ggplot2?

Comment: have you made an attempt of it yet?

Answer (score 16):

There's plenty of ways to do this and you can find them if you spend a few minutes googling it or searching this site.

One way is `ggAcf` and `ggPacf` from the `forecast` package. They create `ggplot2` objects which you can then customize using ggplot syntax and parameters.

```
series <- rnorm(300)
plot <- ggAcf(series)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Actually these functions were not there in previous versions of the forecast package.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the `forecast::ggAcf` function, it also quite fast to do it yourself with ggplot. The only nuisance is that `acf` does not return the bounds of the confidence interval, so you have to calculate them yourself.

## Plotting ACF with ggplot and no other packages required

```
# plot acf with ggplot
ggacf <- function(series) {
  significance_level <- qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(series)))  
  a<-acf(series, plot=F)
  a.2<-with(a, data.frame(lag, acf))
  g<- ggplot(a.2[-1,], aes(x=lag,y=acf)) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") + xlab('Lag') + ylab('ACF') +
          geom_hline(yintercept=c(significance_level,-significance_level), lty=3);

  # fix scale for integer lags
  if (all(a.2$lag%%1 == 0)) {
    g<- g + scale_x_discrete(limits = seq(1, max(a.2$lag)));
  }
  return(g);
}

#example: plot correlogram of an AR(1) process
require('stats');
ggacf(arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.9), n=300));
```

## Example: ACF plotted with ggplot, for an AR(1) process

Below you can see the output from the snippet. The plot

- contains the 95% confidence interval for autocorrelation coefficient
- does not show the autocorrelation at 0, which is always 1 (and makes the plot harder to read in my view)

[image: acf plotted with ggplot]